# object disappearing after using Boolean modifier

Tags: modifiers

[image]

posting this as other post wasn't of help.

i've tried applying all transforms on both object

increasing poly on both objects.

[image]

checking and flipping normals on both objects.

Comment: Can you attach your .blend file?

Comment: there you go :)

Comment: Switch it to the Fast Solver option on the modifier panel.

Comment: still disappearing for me

Comment: Worked fine here! Which version of Blender are you using? - Version: 2.92.0, branch: master, commit date: 2021-02-24 16:25, hash: 02948a2cab44, type: Release under Windows 10 here.

Comment: version: 2.92.0, branch: master, commit date: 2021-02-24 16:25, hash: 02948a2cab44, type: Release
build date: 2021-02-25, 09:31:14
platform: Windows

Answer (score 1):

Go to solver options and activate self intersection

Answer (score 0):

I did a bit of experimenting on your .blend file. Turns out that if I go into edit mode on the cylinders, press <kbd>P</kbd> > *By Loose Parts* (To make them different objects) and then move them to a new collection, and then set the boolean type to collection and put in that cylinder collection, the boolean works and doesn't make the mesh disappear.

Comment: possibly a bug? i just download a portable version of blender (same build) and it worked just fine

Comment: @trburns Maybe, because I have used booleans like this before by adding multiple meshes in one single object. Or maybe if you just remake the scene this bug will go away.

Comment: Some of the cylinders are overlapping too which can cause the modifier problems. Anyhow you seem to be sorted now.

Answer (score 0):

seemed to be a issue with the cylinders. I deleted the cylinders in the original .blend, then imported the cylinders from the test .blend and it worked just fine